# Enter Issuer / Provider name manually in Google Authenticator App

Tags: google-authenticator

In Google Authenticator app, while setting up the account manually (i.e. not scanning the QR Code), how we can enter the issuer name (i.e. provider / service name like Google, Evernote, Facebook, etc..) along with an account name (generally an email / login id).